# Angular Expected the operants to be of similar type or any when using ngIf with type Number

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a model as

```
class AnnouncementDocument {
  Id: String;
  IsDeleted: Boolean;
  Name: String;
  TemporaryName: String;
  Description: String;
  AnnouncementDocumentTypeId: Number;
}
```

in my template i am using

```
*ngIf="announcementDocumentTypeId==1
```

and i get the error

```
[Angular] Expected the operants to be of similar type or any
```

which is right, because 1 in template is treated as string not number

how can i solve the issue ?

Comment: *ngIf="AnnouncementDocumentTypeId===1" ? check the lowercase/uppercase

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To check the type too , you will have to use **`===`** , Just check

```
*ngIf="announcementDocumentTypeId===1
```